# How to change the class of a label using Formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I have the following code, using the latest version of Formatastic 3.1.0.

```
<%= f.input :name, :input_html => { :class => "col-lg-10" }, :label_html => { :class => "col-lg-2" }%>
```

I can change the input_html but I can't find the option to change label html class.  Is there any way to do this?

The output is generated as such (note the omission of "col-lg-2" in label's class).

```
<li class="string input required stringish" id="account_name_input">
<label for="account_name" class="label">Name<abbr title="required">*</abbr></label>
<input id="account_name" class="col-lg-10" type="text" value="" name="account[name]">
</li>
```

Comment: You mean, that `:label_html` doesn't work? Or what is the problem? Can you show the HTML code, which this snippet generates?

Comment: Hi Peter - added the HTML output.  I hope there is a `:label_html` option but I can't find it in the documentation (and it doesn't work as you can see above).

Answer (score 2):

Looking through the documentation and the source code, I don't see a built-in way to do this. (I could always be wrong.) However, perhaps this monkey-patch will work:

*config/initializers/formtastic_monkey_patch.rb*

```
Formtastic::Inputs::Base::Labelling.module_eval do

  def label_html_options
    {
      :for => input_html_options[:id],
      :class => (['label'] + (options[:label_class] || [])).flatten
    }
  end
end
```

This should override Formtastic's default `label_html_options` function, which can be seen in [this file](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/blob/master/lib/formtastic/inputs/base/labelling.rb). Classes would then be added through an array:

```
f.input :my_attribute, :label_class => ['my_class', 'my_other_class']
```

That's my idea, but I'd suggest getting an opinion apart from mine before using it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I ended up using simple_form instead, which I found to be much more customizable.

Comment: @wcheung I figured that you must have found some kind of solution by now. However, I've been going through Formtastic's source code a lot, and so when I saw your question I wanted to see if I could come up with something. It's true that Formtastic is tough to customize, but I'm stuck with it in my current project and am trying to learn what I can!